# Does subscribed stanza trigger a callback?

Tags: strophe

Is there a way to get a callback from a subscribed type stanza ? There's an XML response from server but Strophe does not trigger any callback.

This is what I'm sending:

```
<body rid='576795248' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='e3552b8d'><presence to='user2@localhost' type='subscribed' xmlns='jabber:client' id='2:sendIQ'/></body>
```

And I'm getting:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="set" id="842-543" to="user1@localhost"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster"><item jid="test2@localhost" subscription="both"/></query></iq></body>
```

As you can see, the server is correctly sending a response, but Strophe does not trigger any callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add a handler: addHandler(func, Strophe.NS.ROSTER, 'iq')